# Wait until all the function calls inside for-loop ends its execution - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I have a function which contains another function call inside a for loop.

```
outerFunction(){ 
    for (var j = 0; j < geoAddress.length; j++) {
         innerFunction(j);
    }
}
```

I need to wait till all the calls to innerFunction is complete. If I need parallel execution of these functions, how to achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Could you provide your `innerFunction` body?

Comment: so innerFunction is threaded off?

Comment: assuming that `innerFunction` in asynchronous, use "promises", e.g. https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: You do know that node.js is single threaded, so even if you execute innerFunction asynchronously, only one of those methods are executing per time.? What is the innerFunction ? Does it make a call to separate service or process? How does it work?

Comment: My innerfucntion is querying a mongoDB database. Depending on the j the innerfucntion retrieve data from different mongoDB databases. At the end I need to aggregate all of them.

Comment: Since I haven't seen it mentioned, I would like to recommend that you do not do what you're thinking about doing. By locking up this loop so that all steps are processed before moving on you're locking up your entire application until this loop finishes. This is most likely what you're not looking today - it's better that you rethink what you're doing in such a way that you can make it asynchronous and use Node the way it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the async library. 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/async

Check out the documentation on "whilst". It sounds like it does just what you need.
whilst(test, fn, callback)

```
var count = 0;

async.whilst(
function () { return count < 5; },
function (callback) {
    count++;
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
},
function (err) {
    // 5 seconds have passed
}
```

);

Comment: I think the problem here is that if method is invoked by two different user requests both of those alters the value of count as it is defined as var count = 0; instead of belonging to a certain object instance. (?)

Comment: This question would be perfectly solved by using `async.forEach`.  Why did you post unrelated code using `whilst`?

Comment: He wasn't iterating over each object in the geoAddress array, he was calling his innerFunction with the index integer. forEach didn't seem like as good a fit as whilst for his use case.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit - Doing Things the Node Way Using Q Promise Library**

If you're using the Q promise library, then try the following:

```
outerFunction(){
    var promises = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < geoAddress.length; j++) {
        deferreds.push(innerFunction(j));
    }

    Q.all(promises).then(function(){ 
        // do things after your inner functions run 
    });
}
```

Even if you're not using this particular library, the principle is the same. One should have one's function return a promise or have it wrapped in a promise as in the Q.denodify method, push all calls to an array of promises, pass said array to your library's equivalent of .when() (jQuery) or .all() (Q Promise Library) and then use .then() to do things after all promises are resolved.

Comment: He's using NodeJS, so it's *unlikely* he'll be using jQuery. There *are* other deferred/ promise implementations around though, [such as `q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I edited the answer to demonstrate the user of Q's all() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
outerFunction() { 
    var done = 0;

    function oneThreadDone() {
        done++;
        if (done === geoAddress.length) {
            // do something when all done
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < geoAddress.length; j++) {
         setTimeout(function() { innerFunction(j, oneThreadDone); }, 0);
    }
}
```

and inside inner_function call oneThreadDone() function (reference passed throught param)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use external library for this you could make a scope object such as `process` which keeps track of how many `innerFunction` calls are still pending, and calls outer callback `cb` when it is finished.

The point with this is that you still get the benefits of async execution, but you just make sure that your code won't execute the next part until all innerFunction belonging to outerFunction are actually finished:

```
outerFunction(function() {
    console.log("All done for outerFunction! - What you should do next?");

    // This block is executed when all innerFunction calls are finished.

});
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Example addresses
var geoAddress = ["Some address X", "Some address Y"];

var innerFunction = function(geoAddress, process) { 

    // Your work to be done is here...
    // Now we use only setTimeout to demonstrate async method
    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log("innerFunction processing address: " + geoAddress);

        // Ok, we update the process
        process.done();   

    }, 500);

};

var outerFunction = function(cb) { 

    // Process object for tracking state of innerFunction executions
    var process = { 

        // Total number of work ahead (number of innerFunction calls required).
        count: geoAddress.length,

        // Method which is triggered when some call of innerFunction finishes  
        done: function() {

            // Decrease work pool
            this.count--;

            // Check if we are done & trigger a callback
            if(this.count === 0) { 
                setTimeout(cb, 0);
            }            
        }
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < geoAddress.length; j++) {
        innerFunction(geoAddress[j], process);
    }

};

// Testing our program
outerFunction(function() {
    console.log("All done for outerFunction! - What you should do next?");

    // This block is executed when all innerFunction calls are finished.

});
```

**Output:**

```
innerFunction processing address: Some address X
innerFunction processing address: Some address Y
All done for outerFunction! - What you should do next?
```

Here is **[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HAfwn/1/)**

Cheers.